# Error: Call to a member function hasErrors() on null

Tags: magento2, orders, error, order-status, help-wanted

Error: Call to a member function hasErrors() on null public_html/vendor/magento/module-shipping/Model/Shipping/LabelGenerator.php:78 Stack trace: #0 /home/adminironcar/public_html/vendor/magento/module-shipping/Controller/Adminhtml/Order/Shipment/Save.php(153): Magento\Shipping\Model\Shipping\LabelGenerator->create(Object(Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Shipment), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http)) #1

Helpmeee please, is when creating a shipping label
[image]

Comment: Have you install any third party extension for the Shipment related functionality then try to disable it and then check.

Comment: Yes, I use a third-party shipping package, I need it working with my store in magento, if I disable it, it doesn't work for me: c

Comment: Then you need t debug the actual error from where above things generated.